# Raspberry Pi PWM with Ultrasound Transducers

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, gpio, pwm

I need to generate a 1Mhz short unipolar pulse every 20 seconds to generate an ultrasonic pulse on my ultrasonic transducers. What do you think is the best way to do this? My plan was to connect the transducers to the PWM pins and use pigpio to generate the square wave. I was thinking about doing something along these lines... would this work?

```
import time
import pigpio

pi = pigpio.pi() # Connect to local Pi.

while true
    pi.hardware_clock(18, 1000000) # 1 MHz square wave on gpio#18 (PWM)
    time.sleep(0.5) #wait for 0.5 seconds to shut the signal off
    pi.hardware_clock(18, 0) # turn signal off
    time.sleep(20) #wait 20 seconds before turning signal back on

pi.stop() # Disconnect from local Pi.
```

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the transducer or if this actual piece of code worked as intended to begin with, it is hard to pinpoint you toward the best approach to use.

That being said, your approach seems to be reasonable enough to actually try it out. The hardware clock library should be able to give you a reasonably clean 1MHz square wave. The maximum frequency that is documented is about 30MHz.

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#hardware_clock

If you have any follow up questions, don't hesitate to comment or let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: Got it working sort of thanks. I noticed that my voltage is extremely low, ~35-40mV. Is this normal, I was expecting somewhere around 2-3V. Also I have a separate receiver that is looking for signals reflected back. I am trying to capture a signal there, however, I realized that the pulses I'm sending are being captured on the oscope regardless of whether the receiver is connected. In fact the oscope shows received pulses even when the oscope leads aren't plugged in. Cross checked with a fxn gen, and it works normally. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: If I had to take a couple of wild guesses here (too many variables and yet again I'm not sure of your current setup): slew rate of the raspberry pi prevent a 3.3v output, oscope is catching noises from the emitter instead of simply reading the returning signal, oscope is not powerful enough to clearly read the signal (problems of ground loops and bandwidth related problems happens quite often near 1MHz), improper usage of your probe (use it on 10x mode to better adapt the capacitive impedance of your probes). The fxn gen should work better since the cable is probably a coax cable.